# Вычисления чисел не влезающих в long long int

Tags: c++

Как производить вычисления с числами которые не влезают в `long long int`? Можно разбить число на 2 переменные, в одной из которых хранить первые порядки, а во второй оставшиеся, но есть ли метод проще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону решений для работы с большими числами (*arbitrary-precision arithmetic*):

- [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/)
- [C++ Big Integer Library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/)
- [Boost.Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)

Так же можете посмотреть [сюда](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software).

Comment: GMP имеет проблемы на винде, студией ее собрать очень проблематично было. Из того что определенно стоит добавить - OpenSSL, там есть BN для длинной арифметики. Есть еще MIRACL, но он тормознее OpenSSL на некоторых операциях в разы, к тому же плохо документирован.